# scraping table based on dates with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

im very new with selenium and now im trying to scrape table based on dates from this site https://www.bi.go.id/id/moneter/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx , what i want to scrape is kurs transaction from nov 2015-nov 2020 like this,but i got stuck and confused when im trying to make selenium select filter mata uang and the dates.please tell me what should i do! thank you in advance
[image]

heres my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import re
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Import webdriver to initialise a browser
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bi.go.id/id/moneter/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx")
for m in range(1):
    # Search for the button that allows to go back
    previous = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        ' //*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_biWebKursTransaksiBI_ddlmatauang1"]/option[24]')
    # Make click in that button
    ActionChains(driver).click(previous).perform()
```

when im trying to do things with "FILTER MATA UANG" it gives me this message error

> JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Failed to execute
> 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is
> non-finite.   (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.198)

Answer (score 2):

I assume your problem is that you cant specify the exact date. id suggest you click on the field where you need to input the date "20-Nov-15" using the `find_element_by_xpath().click` function, and then use the

```
element.send_keys(20-Nov-15)
```

and the

```
element.send_keys(ENTER)
```

to confirm it.
handle alike for the other field where you insert "20-Nov-20"
i hope that works :D